# PowerApps Gallery checkbox - Make button visible

Tags: checkbox, gallery, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am creating a canvas powerapp with multiple items to be edited on a screen. I have a gallery with these multiple items, each item has a check box. I need to make a button visible if at least one of the checkbox is checked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its achieved by using the below snippet under Visible property of the button.

`If(CheckboxName.Value=true,true,false)`